# comprobar si dos String han sido invertidos

Tags: java, string, condiciones

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("dame una palabra: ");
        String cadena = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("dame otra palabra:");
        String cadena2 =entrada.nextLine();
```

Teniendo dos strings que pedimos al usuario como podemos saber si el primero por ejemplo hola y el segundo aloh son inversos?

Comment: Has probado a hacer un reverse y compararlo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 1):

tendrías un método en este caso de tipo boolean que devuelva true si la palabra "Hola" es igual a su reverso "aloh" ,primero invertirías la palabra "hola" usando StringBuffer().reverse() y capturando ese nuevo dato en una nueva variable para poder compararlo con la palabra original

```
public class reverse{
        public static boolean validarReverse(String palabra,String reverso){
        boolean validar;        
        String palabaReverse = new StringBuffer(palabra).reverse().toString();
        if(reverso.equalsIgnoreCase(palabaReverse)){
        //comparamos usamos Ignorecase para que no afecten las mayuscula o minuscula de la palabra ingresada
             validar=true;
        }else{
            validar=false;
        }return validar;
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(validarReverse("hola","aloh"));
    }
    
    }
```